# NSIS installer: How to change a property value when value is in next line

Tags: nsis, properties-file

I have a properties file (which I cannot change) where the syntax is:

```
-key[ \r\n]
value
```

When I use

```
${ConfigWrite} "my.properties" "-value $\r$\n" "newValue" $tmp
```

I get

```
-key[ \r\n]
newValue
value
```

I want to have

```
-key[ \r\n]
newValue
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your example makes no sense at all

Comment: And your comment is no help at all

Comment: I don't think ${ConfigWrite} supports \r nor \n because it reads the file line by line.

Comment: I got there already... But maybe there is some other function, I am not aware of... thus the question...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue because `value` was known and only `newValue` a variable.

I used a *ReplaceInFile* function to replace `value` with `newValue`.